# SELinux Enforcing not honouring httpd_enable_homedirs -> off

Tags: apache, permissions, fedora, virtual-directory, selinux

**Why am I able to access `http://localhost/~myusername` in Fedora20 with SELinux set to *Enforcing*, if the `httpd_enable_homedirs` boolean is set to *off*?**

The following is a direct excerpt from the [fedoraproject's wiki on SELinux](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux/apache) about the `httpd_enable_homedirs` boolean:

> httpd by default is not allowed to access users home  directories.   If
>   you  want to allow access to users home directories you need to set the
>   httpd_enable_homedirs boolean and change the context of the files  that
>   you want people to access off the home dir.

I have a directory within the `/home/user/` directory that I had set up in a prior release(F19) to serve content/files on the server (`/home/user/public_html`), marked with the label `httpd_user_content_t`.  The directory is owned by `reg_user:apache`; "regular user" is part of the `apache` group.

However, based on the SELinux documentation, I had assumed that I would be unable to access `http://localhost/~reg_user/` unless the above-mentioned boolean was switched from *off* to **on**; yet, I'm able to do so without any prompts/errors while in `Enforcing` mode.  Was my assumption truly flawed to begin with, or might there be a security risk in my local SELinux policy?

BTW: the server's hosted in `/var/www`

---

## Troubleshoot

After changing the group ownership of the directory back to the `reg_user`'s group, there was no noticeable difference in behavior with the `httpd_enable_homedirs` boolean. However, I have a configuration file for the server that **does** specify the `public_html` directory to be served/mapped to `http://server/~username`:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir public_html
</IfModule>
```

along with a `<Directory>` block containing further restrictions/permissions and access control.

Maybe the server follows these directions at this point regardless of the `httpd_enable_homedirs` boolean; is the SELinux boolean primarily needed during the initial setup for the searchpath permissions?  Since the `/home/user/public_html` directory is labeled with the correct *fcontext* (i.e. `httpd_user_content_t`), that's the only explanation I can come up with to why SELinux is not blocking apache from accessing it.

---

## SELinux policy modules

In an attempt to narrow down the possible cause of this inconsistency I issued the following command (as suggested by user @FeRD) that lists custom/irregular SELinux policy files, which were not provided/owned by the `selinux-policy-targeted` package:

```
[root@hostname etc]# find /etc/selinux -print0 |xargs -0 -n10 rpm -qf |grep "not owned"
file /etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/booleans.local is not owned by any package
file /etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/sandbox.pp.disabled is not owned by any package
file /etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/sandbox.pp is not owned by any package
file /etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/radicale.pp is not owned by any package
file /etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/permissive_bluetooth_t.pp is not owned by any package
file /etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/mod_selinux.pp is not owned by any package
file /etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/mypol.pp is not owned by any package
file /etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/gcl.pp is not owned by any package
file /etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/copr.pp is not owned by any package
file /etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/mailgraph.pp is not owned by any package
file /etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/ports.local is not owned by any package
file /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/netfilter_contexts is not owned by any package
```

Comment: Interesting, because I just hit this in the opposite direction — I couldn't get `http://server/~user/` to serve until I flipped that boolean. I was getting httpd AVC denials for both search and getattr (`/home/user`), and `/var/log/httpd/error_log` showed error AH00035 (search permissions missing on path). However, in my situation neither the files nor the user are owned/members of the apache group. (Nor do they need to be, after flipping the boolean. The public_html tree has the context `httpd_user_content_t`, though.) Perhaps the apache group use is "bypassing" SELinux' homedir logic?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is on your server,but this definitely isn't the case normally.That configuration you mention(/etc/httpd/conf.d/userdir.conf) is a standard part of Fedora apache distribution, everyone has the same config, and it definitely shouldn't bypass SELinux like you say.In fact, I just experimentally tried chgrp-ing my $HOME/public_html tree to apache, and STILL the boolean is respected (so, my guess was wrong there). sudo setsebool httpd_enable_homedirs off, instant 403 errors on reload. sudo setsebool httpd_enable_homedirs on, content is visible again.– FeRD Feb 26 at 0:18

Comment: hmm...I have the httpd_enable_homedirs boolean set to off still, but the server continues to display the list of folders contained within the /home/user/public_html location through localhost/~myusername. Maybe it's a different service that's allowing it? Is that a possibility? Or a different boolean?

Comment: Even with the boolean on/working (or, maybe I should just say, "irrespective of SELinux"), you need perms 711 on the user's homedir and at least 755 on `$USER/public_html` or you'll get Forbidden errors. httpd (running as `apache:apache`) has to have directory browse access to `$USER/public_html/` or it can't serve what's inside it. That's discussed in the comments at the top of `/etc/httpd/conf.d/userdir.html`.

Comment: One thing you could try doing is running the following as root: `find /etc/selinux -print0 |xargs -0 -n10 rpm -qf` — that'll let you know if there's anything foreign installed in selinux, as well as the sources of what's supposed to be there. (Almost everything is owned by `selinux-policy-targeted-$FOO-$BAR.noarch`, normally.) Maybe there's a policy module installed that's granting httpd access to files it shouldn't have?

Comment: At this point, I'm looking into my implementation of the `mod_selinux` package (which is not part of standard `httpd` install on fedora). The documentation is mainly for `postgresql` servers; I'm using `mariadb`.